# Does using a jaxb XMLAdapter affect performance?

Tags: performance, jaxb, adapter

I am unmarshalling a very large XML file using JAXB with an XMLAdapter used to unmarshal one particualar "problem" class. The XMLAdapter is fairly simple, but it is called many times - we are anticipating up to 2 Million times for a single xml file. Our test file is smaller - the adapter is called 200,000 times - but we are noticing a performance hit.  The adapter is fairly standard:

```
public class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, AdaptedClass> {

  public static final String ATTRIBUTE_HREF = "href";

  public AdaptedClass unmarshal(Object obj) throws Exception {

  Element element = null;

  if (obj instanceof Element) {

      element = (Element)obj;
      String id = element.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_HREF);
      AdaptedClass pr = new AdaptedClass();
      pr.setHref(id);                           
      return pr;
  } 
 }
```

My question: Is there overhead in using an adapter? Does, for example, the adapter itself have to be looked up from a table? Could the code inside the adatper slow things down? In my case, the code is fairly simple, so its seems that some similar unmarshalling code would be taking place even if I weren't using the adapter..

Comment: Would specifying an adapter-like class in the binding file be a better solution or is this essentially the same thing as specifying an XMLAdapter?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB 2 ([JSR-222](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

The impact of using an `XmlAdapter` will vary between JAXB implementations (Metro, MOXy, Apache JaxMe, etc), but will primarily consist of the following:

- The efficiency of the code you have supplied in the `XmlAdapter`
- A check to see if an initialized `XmlAdapter` has been passed to the `Marshaller` or `Unmarshaller`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! It brings up a couple of new questions.. Looking at the code above, do you seen any inefficiencies ? and regarding the second item, how could I minimize the time used to make this check? should I be using setAdapter? does the check take longer if don't use it? Thanks again!

Comment: Also wondering if there is any performance difference between putting the annotaition on the package level vs. further down..

Comment: @BradEggers - In your post `AdaptedClass` is your real domain class, and you are using `Object` for the XML representation.  Generally JAXB will treat `Object` as a DOM type.  Ideally you would create a POJO that JAXB could marshal to XML.  For an example see:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html